# Problem of connecting Tomcat server in Netbeans

Tags: web-services, tomcat, netbeans

While deploying my web service I am not able to connect my Tomcat server in NetBeans.
Can you tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of JDK are you using?. If you are using a version of JDK greater than 1.6.0_04, nothing needs to be done,you will just have to use TomCat on your project. If you are using older versions, you may check this link wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEndorsedDirTomcat.

[p2p](http://www.vpn4all.com/)